# Centering tubeless tire

Tags: tire, tubeless

Mounting 700Cx35mm tubeless road tires on 25mm carbon wheels. Tires will NOT go center; always wobble, sometimes 2mm sometimes 10mm. Unmount, soapy water, remount, beads pop and... still not straight. LBS suggested then tried alcohol instead of soapy water; not better. Wobbles not in the same place every time, so it's not the tires. Wheels are true within 1mm. Is it even possible to get reliable/consistent centered mount with zero wobble? How?!?

Comment: Are both your wheels and tires tubeless-ready? Maybe you can try swapping the wheel and tire? This might allow you to narrow the issue down to the tire or the rim. Naturally there is the risk that you will now have the same issue on both wheels. Or you could get lucky and both will miraculously work fine.

Comment: Yes both tires and wheels are tubeless-ready. The tires' beads are just very tight on the rims. I've gotten very close once, but recently broke a spoke and have to start over.

Comment: It certainly is possible, most people have no issues. But it might be impossible for your unfortunate tyre/rim combination...

Comment: Maybe post some photos or a short video?  No guarantee it will help, but it can't _hurt_; the more information the better.

Comment: You said "Wheels are true within 1mm", is that both laterally and radially? This has a good explanation and there are videos on YouTube too: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/wheel-and-rim-truing

Answer (score 2):

Use the thinnest (least built up) tape job that will work for your tire pressure and size needs. Get a dedicated mounting paste and try it at its maximum tubeless rated pressure. Ear protection is a good idea here because the mounting paste is slick and you need maximum pressure, but if it's a tire that wants to ride very low somewhere then there probably won't be an issue with blow-off. Do it "dry" (just the paste, no sealant) and see if it just works. If it doesn't, put a tube in and overinflate a little, then if that works give it an overnight to set in a little, then pop one bead and tubeless it. Rema mounting paste (I've only used the tub pictured here) will not interfere with good "normal" ammonia/latex sealant like Stans or Orange.

[image]

It's rare to both get pops and still have it be uneven. Sometimes in situations like this, I've seen getting bold with overinflating and mounting paste be the only thing that works, but with that recommendation must come the qualifier that it could blow off or (hypothically) damage the tire.

Just because the uneven spots are different every time gives zero indication that it's not the tires at fault. The tires could be undersize and cause this issue as result. The tires being under or the rim being over or some combination are almost certainly what's going on here.